# Hierarchical Injector and dependancy lifetime

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When using Hierarchical Injection, what is the lifetime of dependancies provided in the non-root injector?

**Context:**

My Angular 2 app consists of several sections. There's a `@RouteConfig` at the root component with routes to components `A`, `B` and `C`. Component `B` has a child `@RouteConfig` to subsections `x` and `y`.

```
/A
/B
  /x
  /y
/C
```

Component `x` needs a service `q`. As recommended in [J. Papa's Angular 2 style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a2/README.md#style-a2-041), I provided the service to the injector at the component `x` level, i.e.

```
@xComponent({
    providers: [q]
})
export class xComponent { ... }
```

Service `q` requests and caches some data internally. I was under the impression that services are singletons and on subsequent visits to `/B/x`, the data would be available from cache. However, with the above setup, each time the user opens section `/B/x`, the data is requested again. I put a `console.log("creating q")` in the constructor for service `q` and see that a new instance of the service is created whenever `/B/x` is visited.

If I provide the service at the level of component `/B`, the value is cached when navigating between `/B/x` and `/B/y`, but lost when navigating to either `/A` or `/C`.

It seems the injector is destroyed whenever the component is destroyed. Is this expected behaviour?

What is the right way to configure the app so that the service would not get recreated? Obviously I could provide the service at the root component level, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do fully understand the behavior of the injectors. They are add to there components and are destroyed with there components.

So in your case you really need to add the service as a global one. This will make it a "singleton".

---

**Additional Link**

If you want to learn more about dependency injection in angular2, I can recommend this article: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks, the "are destroyed with the components" part was what I was missing. I wonder - is this documented anywhere? It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the thoughtram.io article, nor in the Angular 2 docs.

Comment: @RonaldZarīts I don't think so, but this is the logic way, because otherwise you would get a ton of Injectors laying around in a huge application.

Answer (score 2):

Angular2 team members stressed several times that instances maintained by DI are **not** singletons (they consider singletons a not-too-good design pattern).

Instead Angular2 DI maintains a single instance per provider.

Angular also creates a tree of injectors that resembles your component tree.

When a component is created a new child injector for this component is created (and also destroyed when the component is destroyed)

The child injector gets its own set of providers from the components `providers:` list.

If the child injector can't find a provider for a requested key (token or type) it forwards the request to the parent injectors.

**Conclusion**

If you want to ensure only one single instance of a service is created in your application, register it with the `providers: [...]` list of your root component (suggested) or alternatively with `bootstrap(...)`.

Comment: From [Angular 2 Hierarchical DI docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html). "There can be only one instance of a service type in a particular injector. But we've learned that we can have multiple injectors operating at different levels of the application's component tree. Any of those injectors could have its own instance of the service." That's all good. I (mistakenly) thought that the injector would somehow stick around. Your comment "..destroyed with the component") is critical. Thanks!